# Media queries not working properly in nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

The media queries of my HTML code works well in desktop. When its integrated with nodejs the media queries not responding properly in desktops. But it works in devices like android and Iphone. I want to fix this because the windows phone not responding to the media queries just like the desktop after nodejs integration.

For example:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
my css code
}
```

Works in the iphones and androids as expected.But ignored in desktop and windows phones, when used with nodejs.

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Can you provide more details, code examples, etc?

Comment: Right. But how are you integrating that with node.js. Are you using any templating engine? Or are you just serving static HTML using express? Also what browser are you using on desktop? I don't think node.js would be the cause for this problem. Problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Ya may be. I am not using any templating engine. Just serving the static HTML without any framework. And I used chrome and firebox browsers in desktop.

Comment: Can't help buddy unless you give specifics. Maybe post a link where it can be checked.

Comment: @RohanGJ http://www.drkeenly.com:1337/ this is the link

Comment: From what I can see from your link you only have `.searchlist .edge2` and `.mlogin` inside `@media (max-width: 768px)` and I can't find an element with `.edge2` and `.mlogin` is inside an element with `display: none`

Comment: @Mathias .searchlist .edge2 & .searchlist .edge1. Those are unused ones. .mlogin is for login modal. minimize the desktop browser width to see the issue. it won't be responsive. the queries will be ignored

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a Windows phone but the login from is repsonsive (`width: 48%`) in Chrome 33, FF 25, and IE11 on Windows 7. When I remove `display: none` from `.mlogbg`

Comment: @Mathias its ok. You can have the view in desktop too, by resizing the window.....

Comment: Can you post a picture? What browser are you using for desktop? As I said the media query do apply when I test it

Comment: Media queries are applying correctly in Chrome as far as I can see. Correct styles are applied when I resize the window. Login box also resizes correctly. Is this a browser specific issue? I am using Chrome 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that when you integrate your stuff into Node, your HTML is still loading the CSS file properly. Node is server-side, media-queries are client-side. The only thing that integration with Node can do is: not serve all the files properly to the client-side.

Most probably: your client is not loading the CSS file. Check your browser's console and you should see the error message(s).

Comment: But the css files are loading only the media queries are ignored. This is the link http://www.drkeenly.com:1337/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer, media query does not work properly when integrated with node.js in developer tool because you might be toggled the device toolbar. If you want to triggered your query make sure you don't toggle the device toolbar in any browsers developer tools.